# JVM - Invalid or Corrupt Jar File

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I've been trying to get my .jar file to launch when you start the computer, so I put it in the startup folder on windows but when I restart my computer to test it, when it tries to launch the .jar it says "invalid or corrupt jar file".

It works fine when I run it everytime, why isn't it working when its launched from startup?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that jar runs normally when you double click/open it directly from windows explorer or from some IDE?

Comment: When I open it directly on windows explorer it works fine